# How to calculate a confidence interval for a binomial, given a specific prior

Tags: probability, statistics

I'm trying to come up with a 95% confidence interval for the click-through-rate of particular advertisement.  It has $x$ clicks out of $n$ impressions so far.

What's the best way to compute this, given that I expect the click-through-rate to be small? I've been told that the "usual" methods of computing a confidence interval don't do well when the true probability $p$ is near 0.

For advertisements, the true click probability is typically in the (0, 0.02) range.  I don't have an exact formula for the prior, but any reasonable approximation centered in the (0, 0.02) range would do.

Is there a nice formula of something like

```
(lower, upper) = confidence_interval(x, n, prior_p, 0.95)
```

out there?

Or alternately, has anyone out there used one of the "usual" confidence interval formulas in this situation, and can confirm that it produces "close enough" results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible thing to do would be to calculate your confidence interval using a use a [Beta distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution)

For example the following R code

```
ci <- function(x, n, prior, conf) { 
      c(qbeta((1 - conf) / 2,   prior[1] + x,  prior[2] + n -x) ,
        qbeta((1 + conf) / 2,   prior[1] + x,  prior[2] + n -x)  )  }         

prior <- c(1,99)
ci(   0,      0, prior, 0.95)
ci(  20,   2000, prior, 0.95)
ci(2000, 200000, prior, 0.95)
```

produces these results

```
> ci(   0,      0, prior, 0.95)
[1] 0.0002557027 0.0365757450
> ci(  20,   2000, prior, 0.95)
[1] 0.006203473 0.014677571
> ci(2000, 200000, prior, 0.95)
[1] 0.009568703 0.010440574
```

Comment: Yeah, the Beta distribution is exactly what I want.  How complicated is that qbeta() function?  I'd like to implement it in Python (preferably with no external dependencies).

Comment: Okay, I looked at the qbeta.c file inside the R source code - it's pretty gnarly :)  There's also a Python binding out there for R.  So I could just use that, or worst-case translate the C to Python.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this will help:

R code

require(LearnBayes)

q1 <- list(p=0.025, x=1e-10) # can't use zero for this function

q2 <- list(p=0.975, x=0.02)

beta.select(q1,q2)

This gives values of a & b for an estimated beta prior with a 95% CI of 0-0.02.
Given that you're approximating a probability, beta seems like the most appropriate distribution to use, a priori.

Answer (score 0):

You can always calculate lower and upper numerically. I'm not sure how the confidence interval is usually defined (Bayesian? likelihood?), but surely you can scan over $p$ and determine what you want numerically.

Alternatively, you can try the Poisson approximation, which works if $np$ is small. If $np$ is large then the normal approximation should work, and this probably the assumption underlying the usual formula, whatever it is.

Comment: Thanks for the numerical integration idea.  As far as Poisson, that seems like just another approximation that I'd rather avoid.  I want something that's as exact as possible.